# Prevent Unique Data From Being Inserted into Table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have two tables. On called People and one called Meetings. The People table has the following columns: iId (primary key, serial) and sName (varchar(30)). Meetings has the following columns: iId (primary key, serial), iPerson1 (iId of an entry in the People table), iPerson2 (iId of an entry in the People table) and dtDate (date).

I want to have a constraint on the Meetings table so that I don't get two rows that have the same two people but in different columns and the same date. I want to avoid:

```
iid    iPerson1    iPerson2    dtDate
1      1           2           '2013-01-01'
2      2           1           '2013-01-01'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems strange that a meeting is limited to just two people. If that is the case, your data structure is ok, but I would expect a `MeetingsPeople` junction table.

You can accomplish what you want in several ways.  One way is with a functional index:

```
create unique index idx_meetings_3
    on meetings(least(iPerson1, iPerson2), greatest(iPerson1, iPerson2), dtdate);
```

Another approach is to combine two constraints.  One a unique constraint on the three columns and the other a requirement that iPerson1 be less than iPerson2:

```
create unique index idx_meetings_3 on meetings(iPerson1, iPerson2, dtdate);

check (iPerson1 < iPerson2);
```

If you take this approach, then certain `insert`s and `update`s will fail, because the persons are in the wrong order.  That can be handled by a trigger or by application-level logic.